# Radarr + Transmission + Docker; Remote Pathing goes wrong

Tags: docker, transmission, plex

I have a Ubuntu Server with docker.
I'm running Radarr and Transmission-VPN as containers but I cannot make they see the same folder or import the movie correctly, I have the movie downloaded but Radarr cannot pick it up.

I already tried a lot of mappings and some of the Remote Mapping, but I think that I'm doing something wrong

Some example of my docker-compose file:

```
#TRANSMISSION-VPN
  transmission-vpn:
    container_name: transmission-vpn
    image: haugene/transmission-openvpn
    restart: always
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    devices:
      - /dev/net/tun
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
      - 1.0.0.1
    ports:
      - "9002:9091"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/transmission-vpn:/data
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads:/data/watch
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads/completed:/data/completed
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads/incomplete:/data/incomplete
...
#RADARR
  radarr:
    image: "linuxserver/radarr"
    container_name: "radarr"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9003:7878"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/radarr:/config
      - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads:/downloads
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads/completed:/data/completed
      - ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/media/movies:/movies
...
```

I want to have all the mapping done right or maybe some help in how I can do the Remote Mapping...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved:

I removed the:

```
- ${USERDIR}/nas/carlostiberiojr/downloads/completed:/data/completed
```

from Radarr

**AND:**

Configured the Remote Path Mappings as follow:

**Host:** Radar host (in my case 192.168.1.2)

**Remote Path:** /data/completed/ (where transmission is saving the completed download)

**Local Path:** /downloads/completed/ (where it will be REACHABLE by Radarr)